# 404 for packages install libmysqlclient15-dev

Tags: mysql, apt, installation

I try to install mysql-dev package on Debian Lenny webserver.
On my local home server, the same version it installs right but on the webserver
I get a strange error.

I hope someone can help me with this one.

```
# sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcups2 libsasl2-modules-sqlite3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  zlib1g-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient15-dev zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 7753kB of archives.
After this operation, 26.7MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  zlib1g-dev libmysqlclient15-dev
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://mirrors.nl.kernel.org lenny/main zlib1g-dev 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg-12
  404 Not Found
Err http://mirrors.nl.kernel.org lenny/main libmysqlclient15-dev 5.0.51a-24+lenny5
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main libmysqlclient15-dev 5.0.51a-24+lenny5
  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nl.kernel.org/debian/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g-dev_1.2.3.3.dfsg-12_amd64.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/m/mysql-dfsg-5.0/libmysqlclient15-dev_5.0.51a-24+lenny5_amd64.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Thanks in advance.

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Debian Lenny is not supported any more. As indicated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Lenny#Releases), it is supported until 2012-02-06.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it means I can't install this package now? I have to upgrade first to an other 'supported' version?

Comment: Yes, you can not install new packages. You have to upgrade to a supported version.